# "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly" exception at registration of service using types from dynamically loaded assembly

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, assembly-loading

## App overview

I am working on WPF/MVVM application, which is sort of an expansion of functionality for another desktop application (let us call it ***Application X***).
I am trying to use layered approach with multiple projects covering different concerns: presentation, infrastructure, application etc.

## External DLL

It uses external DLL library with API to application X. Once in a while there is a new major version of application X released together with new version of DLL library. Library is referenced in all projects with `"Copy Local No"` setting. Proper version of library is loaded dynamically from application X installation path, based on user selection at app start, using assembly resolve event `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`. This solution is proposed by library provider in their documentation. There was no issue with this approach until now.

## Problem description

Service interface is defined in project `AppName.Application`, which has properties of type from external library:

```
using Library.DLL;

namespace AppName.Application.FeatureX
{
    public interface IService
    {
        TypeFromLibrary PropertyX { get; }
    }
}
```

Concrete implementation of this service is placed in separate project `AppName.Infrastructure`:

```
using Library.DLL;

namespace AppName.Infrastructure.FeatureX
{
    public class Service : IService
    {
        TypeFromLibrary PropertyX { get; }
    }
}
```

I am using dependency injection container from `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, with service registration at app startup with `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`.

```
services.TryAddSingleton<Service>();
services.TryAddSingleton<IService>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<Service>());
```

Order of actions at startup is as follows:

1. Build host (register dependencies, logger, configuration etc.)
2. Display View for version selection
3. Resolve dynamic assembly based on user selection

At app startup following exception is thrown, **just before the call** of method registering service into DI container:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Library.DLL, Version=x.x.x.x, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

## Debugging

I have tried to find, what is the real problem and I can't find anything online on such specific situation. I have tried the following just to debug the issue:

**1. Remove IService registration**

Runtime error at registration is thrown.

**2. Remove Service registration**

Runtime error at registration disappears, but obviously service is not resolved.
It seems there is no issue with registering interface, but there is one with registering implementation.
I don't see the connection.

**3. Place IService/Service in the same project**

Runtime error at registration disappears.
Why does service registration requires the assembly to be loaded, when interface/implementation are in two different projects and why it doesn't happen, when they are in the same project ?
This is not a solution for me, as I want to have a clear separation for contracts, which application layers is using and the implementation of service.

## Goal

I could build host after assembly selection, but I don't want to, because assembly selection view communicates with application layer via ViewModel with dependency injected services.
Is there anything that must be setup at configuration level ?